# How to do post request from a static site to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf, static-site

I first created rails app in one domain `app.example.com` and static site in another domain `www.example.com`. Then added `devise` gem in the rails app and created a login form in the static site. Here is the code for the login form:

```
<form action="app.example.com/users/sign_in" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="admin@gmail.com">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password" value="password">
    <input name="authenticity_token", value="", type="hidden">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is it possible to redirect to a rails app after login from static site because it required authenticity_token and is difficult to generate authenticity_token in static site and also there may be the issue of `csrf`.

Comment: I think that a better solution would be a view in your rails app with the devise login form (no layout) and have an iframe of that view in your static site.

Comment: And how to redirect to `app.example.com` after making iframe of that login page? Rails app is also showing in iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable the [CSRF protection](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) for this action by subclassing `Devise::SessionsController`.

```
# app/controllers/my_sessions_controller.rb
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create
end
```

Make sure you change the `devise_for :users` call in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'my_sessions' }
```